# How to avoid the "pager" in mailx?

Tags: mailx, pager

Having many short mail messages in my inbox, it's quite annoying that even short messages are sent though a pager (less), requiring to press 'q' before I can view the next message (for example).

I read the manual page about pager, but none of these did work:

```text
PAGER= mailx
set pager=
unset pager
unset PAGER
```

How can I disable the pager?
I'm using mailx 12.5 of SLES 15 SP3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two major problems that prevent an easy solution for the problem:

1. As indicated in [the `mailx` man page](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html) (SLES ships Nail’s `mailx`), “Variables in the environment passed to `mailx` cannot be unset.”
2. `PAGER` (as set from within `mailx`) cannot have parameters, so something like `set PAGER="LESS=-F less"` or `set PAGER="sh -c LESS=-F less"` do not work.
   To make things worse, there is no output if you try something like `set PAGER="less -F"`.

So the alternatives are:

1. `mailx` can be configured to skip the pager if a message fits in a single screen by setting the `crt` option (that requires the number of lines of the terminal normally): add

   ```
   set crt
   ```

   to your `.mailrc`.  Without a value, the version of `mailx` available in SLES uses the current screen height; [POSIX doesn’t specify the behaviour when `crt` is set without a value](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html#tag_20_75_13_02), so a POSIX-compliant approach is either to set it to 99999 (to always skip the pager) or a typical value for your work environment (to only use the pager when necessary).
2. The pager can also be replaced with a non-paging display tool, *e.g.* `cat` when starting `mailx` from a Bourne-shell-like interpreter:

   ```
   PAGER=cat mailx
   ```
3. If your pager is `less`, you can ask it to quit without prompting if it has less than a screen’s worth of text to display, using its `-F` option (again using `sh` syntax):

   ```
   LESS=F mailx
   ```

   If you want to combine `-F` with other options set in your `LESS` variable, use

   ```
   LESS="$LESS -F" mailx
   ```

   This can be enabled in general by exporting `LESS=F` (and any other `less` option you want to enable by default) in your shell startup script.

   In versions of `less` older than 530, you may need to combine `-F` and `-X` (`LESS=FX`).

Comment: OK that's actually a solution wile I'm waiting for better answers. Can I make such a setting permanent (i.e. automatic) inside `less`?

Comment: `set crt` is a good idea. If it could do the magic that `resize` can do (i.e. find out the height of the terminal) all would be just "automatic".